# SwiftUI TabView with nested NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

to summarize my problem:
My application contains a `TabView` on the root level. The children of the TabView must be searchable (using the apple native `.searchable(...)` modifier. Additionally at least one of the views must be able to push a third view on the stack which hides the TabBar on the bottom.

The problem with that is that both approaches: Using one single NavigationView in the root view and using additional navigation views inside the child views did not work.

Using only one NavigationView:

- TabBar gets overlayed when navigating to another acitivty ✔
- Not searchable ❌

Using nested NavigationViews:

- TabBar is always visible also in the full screen activity ❌
- Desired title + search behavior ✔

Root View:

```swift
public enum TestNavItemId: String, CaseIterable, Equatable {
    case activity1 = "activity1"
    case activity2 = "activity2"

    public static func == (lhs: NavItemId, rhs: NavItemId) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                Activity1()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey(TestNavItemId.activity1.rawValue))
                        }
                        .tag(TestNavItemId.activity1)
                Text("Nothing to see here")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "fire")
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey(TestNavItemId.activity2.rawValue))
                        }
                        .tag(TestNavItemId.activity2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity1:

```swift
struct Activity1: View {

    @State private var query: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Content")
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Full Screen View")) {
                    Text("Open full screen view")
                }
            }
                    .searchable(text: $query)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Apple doesn’t want the tab view to be hidden when used. It is mentioned in the design guidelines. The apps that do it have a custom design. The second is the “correct” approach. With the first you will find many bugs.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73162708/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi no unfortunately this does not solve the problem of `NavigationView` behavior (searchable, nav bar items). - but thx!

Comment: Thx @loremipsum - doesn't that mean that all chat messengers using `TabViews` must use some hacky workaround to hide the TabBar?

Comment: Using *nested* NavigationView is invalid in SwiftUI, there should be only one in stack. Just be aware. I don't see what can be bad there with searchable and nav bar items, but ok.

Comment: They just have a custom one. Not hacky just custom.

Comment: Also, what I meant that the second is correct I mean that the navigation view at the top of your code should not be there. Each tab should have its own navigation view. There should not be a shared navigation view.