# In SwiftUI, if there is a TabView inside a NavigationView, the navigation toolbar continues to stack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Problem

[image]

I was expecting the existing toolbar to disappear whenever the next view is pushed.

However, it behaves differently than I expected.

When the next view is pushed, it comes in with the existing toolbar remaining.

Why is this happening?

**p.s. Our app requires the tabbar to always be exposed.
So I can't use navigationview inside tabview.**

## My code

**CustomNavigation**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

public enum GPToolbarItem {
  case logo(_ didTap: (() -> Void)? = nil)
  case magnifyingGlass(_ didTap: (() -> Void)? = nil)
  case chevronLeft(_ didTap: (() -> Void)? = nil)
  case heart(_ didTap: (() -> Void)? = nil)
  case text(_ didTap: (() -> Void)? = nil)
}

extension GPToolbarItem: Identifiable {
  public var id: UUID { .init() }
}

public extension View {
  func gpNavigationTitle(_ title: Text) -> some View {
    return modifier(GPNavigationTitleModifier(title: title))
  }

  func gpToolbarItem(leftItems: [GPToolbarItem], rightItems: [GPToolbarItem]) -> some View {
    return modifier(GPToolbarItemModifier(leftItems: leftItems, rightItems: rightItems))
  }
}
```

```swift
struct GPToolbarItemModifier: ViewModifier {
  private let leftItems: [GPToolbarItem]
  private let rightItems: [GPToolbarItem]
  
  init(leftItems: [GPToolbarItem], rightItems: [GPToolbarItem]) {
    self.leftItems = leftItems
    self.rightItems = rightItems
  }
  
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
          ItemBuilder(items: self.leftItems)
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
          ItemBuilder(items: self.rightItems)
        }
      }
  }
  
  @ViewBuilder
  private func ItemBuilder(items: [GPToolbarItem]) -> some View {
    ForEach(items) {
      switch $0 {
      case let .logo(tapGesture):
        Button("logo") {
          tapGesture?()
        }
      case let .magnifyingGlass(tapGesture):
        Button("magnifyingGlass") {
          tapGesture?()
        }
      case let .chevronLeft(tapGesture):
        Button("chevronLeft") {
          tapGesture?()
        }
      case let .heart(tapGesture):
        Button("heart") {
          tapGesture?()
        }
      case let .text(tapGesture):
        Button("text") {
          tapGesture?()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct GPNavigationTitleModifier: ViewModifier {
  private let title: Text
  
  init(title: Text) { self.title = title }
  
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
      .navigationTitle(self.title)
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NavigationAndTabApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
          NavigationView {
            TabView {
              GPNavigationPreview()
                .tabItem {
                  Image(systemName: "house")
                  Text("home")
                }
              SwiftUIView()
                .tabItem {
                  Image(systemName: "house")
                  Text("home")
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}

struct GPNavigationPreview: View {
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: GPNavigationPreview2()) {
          Text("GPNavigationPreview")
        }
      }
      .gpNavigationTitle(.init("GPNavigationPreview"))
      .gpToolbarItem(leftItems: [.logo()], rightItems: [.magnifyingGlass()])
    }
}

struct GPNavigationPreview2: View {
    var body: some View {
      NavigationLink(destination: GPNavigationPreview3()) {
        Text("GPNavigationPreview2")
      }
      .gpToolbarItem(leftItems: [.chevronLeft()], rightItems: [.heart()])
    }
}

struct GPNavigationPreview3: View {
    var body: some View {
      Text("GPNavigationPreview3")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hello! Please have a look on my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352327/4981515 . It should help.

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, our app requires the tabbar to always be exposed. So i can't use navigationview inside tabview.

Comment: Can you attach the code for the parent View that calls your NavigaionView? It seems that you may need to modify the code in the parent view.

Comment: @Cheolhyun 
Thanks for your advice.

I think it's a problem with TabView.

I know the problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.
I've updated it with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `TabView`.

The reason why the NavigationToolbar Items in the first View don't disappear in the second View is because you declared the `.toolbar` in the `NavigationView`.

Moving where you declare the `.toolbar` should fix it, like this

```swift
struct GPNavigationPreview: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: GPNavigationPreview2()) {
                Text("GPNavigationPreview")
            }
            .gpToolbarItem(leftItems: [.logo()], rightItems: [.magnifyingGlass()])  // <--  2. to here
        }
        .gpNavigationTitle(.init("GPNavigationPreview"))
        // .gpToolbarItem(leftItems: [.logo()], rightItems: [.magnifyingGlass()])  // <--  1. move
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful for me. Also, in debugging my code, GPNavigationPreview I was using NavigationView in . When I remove that NavigationView, it works perfectly. Thank you for the answer.