How do hide tab bar when going into view?
I have a TabView in my SwiftUI app, and one of the tabs contains a list with NavigationLinks to other views. I don't want the tab bar to be on the screen when I navigate to a new view, so it is only visible on the primary tabs and not on the subsequent pages.
Here is how my ContentView.swift looks:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            FirstTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("First Tab", systemImage: "house.fill")
                }

            SecondTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second Tab", systemImage: "star.fill")
                }
            
            ThirdTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Third Tab", systemImage: "person.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

And here’s an example of one of the views (SecondTabView) containing a NavigationLink:
import SwiftUI

struct SecondTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Go to Detail View")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Second Tab")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondTabView()
    }
}

When I navigate to DetailView, I want the tab bar to be hidden. I’ve tried using .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) but the behavior is not smooth—there is a janky transition where the tab bar disappears before the new view slides in, and it reappears after sliding back.

If you use .sheet then that will hide everything underneath inc. the tab bar

Is it helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73148209/swiftui-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-equivalent?

Use NavigationStack like this
@main
struct LYFSuitApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack{
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

For Navigation
Use Only
struct SecondTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Go to Detail View")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Second Tab")
    }
}

struct SecondTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondTabView()
    }
}

